# How to disable/enable HTML5 Video tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Below code is not working, How can disable HTML5 video tag

```
document.getElementById("vidEle").disabled=true;
```

If I use

```
document.getElementById("vidEle").controls=false;
```

Still I am able to play using right click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if we knew the browser you are using, but here are some workarounds:

You can set a new block element on top of it with the same size as the video player with a translucent background using css.

Or you could set the style of your element to display none:

```
document.getElementById("vidEle").style.display="none";
```

And lastly you can also unload the content of the vidEle element. One last thing, make sure the video is not playing if you choose to use the "display:none" method.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the video source so the video won't be able to play :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to disable the context menu like this:

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" controls>
 <source src="somedir/somevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: That's of no effect

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the browser, but try the accepted answer, that one works better since you add a non visible div on top of the video and that will catch every right click.

Answer (score 0):

```
function turnOffCamera() {
      const videoTracks = currentStream.getVideoTracks();
      videoTracks.forEach((track) => {
        isVideoOpen = !isVideoOpen;
        track.enabled = isVideoOpen; // Disable the video track
        toggleTheCameraButtonText();
      });
    }

function turnOffAudio() {
  const audioTracks = currentStream.getAudioTracks();
  audioTracks.forEach((track) => {
    isAudio = !isAudio;
    track.enabled = isAudio; //Disable the audio track
    toggleTheAudioButtonText();
  });
}
```

track.enabled worked for me